# Imports using Relative Path from Python Project Root

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pipenv

If we have a Python project whose directory structure is as shown ([also available on Github](https://github.com/athenawisdoms/python_imports_problem))

```
foo
    /data
        test.dat
    /src
        /foo
            /lib
                __init__.py
                world.py
            __init__.py
            hello.py
```

How can we set things up such that modules can be imported from any file via `foo.<something>`, where `foo` is the directory inside `src`, and `<something>` is the relative path from `foo`?

The reading of the file `test.dat` should work too in such a directory structure.

**foo/__init__.py**

```
import pathlib

DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.absolute() / 'data'
```

**foo/hello.py**

```
from foo.lib.world import world

def hello():
    print("Hello", world())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

**foo/lib/world.py**

```
from foo import DATA_DIR

def world():
    with open(f'{DATA_DIR}/test.dat') as f:
        name = f.readline()
        return "world, " + name
```